# Query and order by total fee from many stores

Tags: sql

I have a database schema in image below. 
[Here is a database schema online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3615cf)

For example, a customer want to buy:

```
service 1 quantity 5
service 2 quantity 2
```

I want to find a stores that has service 1 and 2, and order by total price.

Do I need to first query all stores that provides these services.

Then run loop to calculate total_price and order by total price?

Has anyone have a better solution?
Please suggest me.
Thank you

[image: Screen Shot 2017-01-09 at 12.21.56 AM.png]

Comment: Please tag with db platform.  Show sample table data and expected output.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What do you mean by "have services with quantity"? There is no column named "quantity" in the StoreService table. Can a store have a lot of absolutely identical services? Then why should they be in different rows?

Comment: There is a field named `available`, I assume you want all `available=1` services.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I have just already update my question.
Please check again.
Thank everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to store the services a customer wants to buy in a temporary table, e.g. `quotation`, such that the combination of requested `serviceId` and `quantity` can be handled by a subsequent sql query.

Temporary tables exist in the current session only, do not conflict with other sessions and are destroyed automatically when session ends. Many databases support temporary tables, yet with different syntax.

As you posted a sample on SQLFiddle using MySQL, I provided a solution based on MySQL syntax (and temporary table restrictions in MySQL). Note: It seems that SQLFiddle cannot handle temporary tables; Therefore, I copied your schema and my extension to [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/UAEF30848).

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS request (
  serviceId int,
  quantity int
);

insert into quotation (serviceId, quantity) values (1,5), (2,2);

create temporary table nrOfServices as (select count(distinct serviceId) as nr from quotation);
```

Note that MySql does not allow to use a temporary table twice in the same query, which would be necessary for the following query. Therefore, helper table `nrOfServices` (again temporary) counting the number of services requested is introduced).

The following query should then retrieve all stores that can deliver all requested services together with the total price:

```sql
select ss.storeId, sum(ss.price * r.quantity) as total
from store_service ss join quotation r on ss.serviceId = r.serviceId
group by ss.storeId
having count(ss.serviceId) = (select nr from nrOfServices)
order by total desc
```